# Application Localization for dynamic text in android app

Tags: android

my android application will fetch data  from web service, I want that user would b able to change his local & get data in that language. So static string xml file wnt help me and for google translate, need to pay. Which can b another way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the dynamic data as multi locale in server. Pass current language as argument to the web service and fetch relevant data.

Comment: thnx but i hv kept this option as last solution coz this data will b news update.Server will send data in en_US (English). & might b possible that user change his local after data download. In that case content wnt b able to change.